# how to Excute more than one ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() in one function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to execute javascript function from server side, so i added following line:

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "@msg", "ValidateRequiredFields('" + txtRequiredFieldValidation.ClientID + "');", true);
```

it works fine. but i want to execute same JavaScript function immediately after above statement. 
so i added following lines :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "@msg", "ValidateRequiredFields('" + txtEmailValidation.ClientID + "');", true);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "@msg", "ValidateRequiredFields('" + txtOnlyNumbersValidations.ClientID + "');", true);
```

but i noticed that only first one startupscript executes.. why? how can i execute multiple startupscript in one function?

Comment: Doesn't appending the other call in the first one work for you ? `"ValidateRequiredFields(Email);ValidateRequiredFields(onlynumeric);"`

Comment: Great ..You may choose to accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx)

> The script block added by the RegisterStartupScript method executes when the page finishes loading but before the page's OnLoad event is raised. The script blocks are not guaranteed >to be output in the order they are registered. If the order of the script blocks is >important, use a StringBuilder object to gather the scripts together in a single string, and >then register them all in a single client script block.

So putting the call together should work for you

```
"ValidateRequiredFields('" + txtEmailValidation.ClientID + "');
 ValidateRequiredFields('" + txtOnlyNumbersValidations.ClientID + "');"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `key` parameter has to be **different**. It can't be both `@msg`, it will replace the *first* one with *second* one

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "@msg1", "ValidateRequiredFields('" + txtEmailValidation.ClientID + "');", true);
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "@msg2", "ValidateRequiredFields('" + txtOnlyNumbersValidations.ClientID + "');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about appending your calls like this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "@msg", 
  "ValidateRequiredFields('" + txtEmailValidation.ClientID + "');
  ValidateRequiredFields('" + txtOnlyNumbersValidations.ClientID + "');",
  true);
```