# open multiple tab for my page in asp.net in a loop

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, web

I want in this `foreach` to open a new tab for another page with data I pass to it through sessions.

More information:

- I have a GridView from which I select Clients
- I want to open new tab for each client selected in the GridView

However it only opens a tab for the last client. Is there a solution?

```
Protected Sub APPReport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles APPReport.Click
    For Each Item2 As GridViewRow In ClientsGv.Rows
        Dim ChckClient As CheckBox = CType(Item2.FindControl("SlctClient"), CheckBox)
        If ChckClient.Checked Then               
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('AppraisalReportView.aspx ','_blank')", True)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: And the question is????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Excute more than one ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() in one function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166392/how-to-excute-more-than-one-clientscript-registerstartupscript-in-one-function)

Comment: in the foreach it's not going to redirected page until the loop is ended

Comment: and show only the data of last client

Comment: i want for each time loop go through scriptmanager to open my another page that show data in new tab

Comment: but what happens it's only go through and the data page open for last item in loop when it go to end sub or end of the function

Comment: Read the link I posted. It explains exactly what the problem is and how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks guys i solved it in script manager there is a parameter called key i had to make it unique i changed "popup" to some unique value each time in loop